# Adding a column to select statement adds more rows?

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to add a column from a joined table but when I do it returns more rows. Here is what the original query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ppa.*
FROM pbf_PayableApproval ppa WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PayableDetail pd
ON ppa.PybleHdrID = pd.PybleHdrID
INNER JOIN TransactionType tt WITH (NOLOCK)
ON tt.TrnsctnTypID = pd.TrnsctnTypID
WHERE ppa.ApprovedByUserID IS NULL
AND ppa.Approved = 'Y'
ORDER BY ApprovalID
```

It returns about 85 rows

But then I add a column like so and it returns more than 200..

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.TrnsctnTypDesc, ppa.*
FROM pbf_PayableApproval ppa WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PayableDetail pd
ON ppa.PybleHdrID = pd.PybleHdrID
INNER JOIN TransactionType tt WITH (NOLOCK)
ON tt.TrnsctnTypID = pd.TrnsctnTypID
WHERE ppa.ApprovedByUserID IS NULL
AND ppa.Approved = 'Y'
ORDER BY ApprovalID
```

Comment: Of course. The `distinct` command checks all columns you select. And in the second query you have simply more variation in your records than in the first.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is looking at *all* the columns in the select list.  This is easy to see.  Consider this data:

```
X    Y
1    a
1    b
1    c
```

The query:

```
select distinct x
from t;
```

returns one row -- with the value `1`.

The query:

```
select distinct x, y
from t;
```

returns all three rows.

In general, if you want one or more combinations of columns to be distinct, then you can use `group by`.  Remember to use aggregation functions for the rest of the columns.  So this query:

```
select x, min(y), max(y0
from t
group by x;
```

returns one row per `x` (i.e. one row), with the minimum and maximum values for `y`.